Python does not throw IndexError when evaluating if condition with 'and' operator
I am currently helping a friend with getting into python and I came across this snippet of code, where I was unable to understand what was happening.
def lbd_red(s):
    try:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i].isalpha() and s[i+1].isdigit():
                if s[i].isdigit() and s[i+1].isdigit():
                    print("smth")

        return True
    except IndexError:
        return False

I would expect this function to always return False, as the if statement essentially does nothing for the control flow, but should always throw an IndexError when evaluating s[i+1]. Yet somehow this is not what is happening. Here are a few examples of function returns:
>> lbd_red("hu3")
True
>> lbd_red("hu3e")
False
>> lbd_red("hue3")
True
>> lbd_red("hue34")
True
>> lbd_red("hue34e")
False
>> lbd_red("hue33")
True
>> lbd_red("hue3e")
False

I have also tried debugging this code and when I watch s[i+1], I can see the IndexError ocurring, but it just does not seem to be thrown in the actual code.
I am currently using Python 3.10.0, but I have also tried it on Python 3.12.
PS: Yes, I know that the print statement will never be reached, but this is just some random code, its usefulness is not relevant to the question.

The index-error will only occur when the last character is not a digit, since at that point i+1 will be out of bounds. The isalpha check guards against this, since Python boolean expressions short-circuit. To fix the out of bounds issue, use range(len(s) - 1).

Okay, so as I was writing this Question, my Brain came up with a possible solution (rubber ducky debugging style). Maybe somebody could still confirm my hunch or share more info (I do find this phenomenon quite interesting).
I think the 'issue' is caused by python optimizing its evaluation, by skipping over the second parameter of the and operator if the first one is False already. To elaborate, if s[i].isalpha() is False the and operator automatically evaluates to False without checking the second operand, thereby saving time in not computing the second expression.
To test this I wrote a function with reversed operands:
def lbd_rev(s):
    try:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i+1].isdigit() and s[i].isalpha():
                if s[i+1].isdigit() and s[i].isdigit():
                    print("smth")

        return True
    except IndexError:
        return False

And now, as I would have expected of the first example as well, all calls return False.
>> lbd_red("hu3")
False
>> lbd_red("hu3e")
False
>> lbd_red("hue3")
False
>> lbd_red("hue34")
False
>> lbd_red("hue34e")
False
>> lbd_red("hue33")
False
>> lbd_red("hue3e")
False


I'm also interested if anyone has come across this being intentionally used in actual code?
